# ckeditor doesn't show cursor in IE6/7/8?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

The cursor won't show unless you start to type.

This problem exists with the samples in its release.

Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I saw a similar problem in 3.0.1.  When I clicked in an editor with very little content, the cursor did not appear.  They corrected the problem in v3.1.